# What is the difference between luminosity and absolute magnitude?

Tags: the-sun

I am writing a one page essay front and back about the H-R diagram, I am supposed to describe what is on it and how we use them. But I don't know the difference between luminosity and absolute magnitude.

Comment: You should start by looking up what "Luminosity" and "Absolute Magnitude" are. Stack Exchange is a place to come for answers after you have already done some research and tried your best to figure out the answer.

Comment: Google is a good friend. You can ask it, and it will direct you to Wikipedia which is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Luminosity is the total energy output of a star per unit time. For example, our own Sun has a luminosity of $3.828\times 10^{26}\ \mathrm{Joules/second}$. Our Sun outputs more energy in a single second than [the entire world consumes in a year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_energy_consumption).

The absolute magnitude is, in some ways, analogous to luminosity in that it is a measure of the energy output of a star. The definition of absolute magnitude is that it is the magnitude a star would have if it were 10 parsecs from an observer. Obviously understanding this definition requires understanding the [magnitude system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_magnitude), which is outside the scope of the question and I will not be explaining it here.